# Join en una relacion laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola buenas tardes saludos soy nuevo en laravel y estoy tratando de hacer algo como lo siguiente, hacer un join de los productos que traigo en una categoría con una tabla de compras, pero me sale error, no se si como lo estoy haciendo sea posible. De antemano gracias...

```
 class Categoria extends Model 
    {
        protected $table = "categorias";
        protected $primaryKey = "idCategoria";
    
        public function productos()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Producto::class, "id_categoria", "idCategoria");

    }
    }

class Producto extends Model 
{
    protected $table = "productos";
    protected $primaryKey = "idProducto";

    public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class);
    }
}

class Compra extends Model 
{
    protected $table = "compras";
    protected $primaryKey = "idCompra";
    protected $fillable = [
        'idCompra', 'idProducto'
    ];
}
    
    $categorias = Categoria::with('productos')
    ->join('compras', 'compras.idProducto', '=', 'productos.idProducto')
    ->get();
```

Comment: en tus campos id los dos tienen el nombre `id` ? o tienen nombre por ejemplo `id_categoria` ?

Comment: si podrías agregar las tablas que interactúan, para que alguien que tenga mas conocimiento te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Ya agregue los modelos, gracias...

Comment: ¿Qué error obtienes?

Comment: La consulta es la que esta debajo, el error es el siguiente: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'productos.idProducto'

Comment: Y que relación guarda Compra con los otros dos modelos?

Comment: Estoy intentando unir los productos obtenidos con su respectiva compra mediante el siguiente código: $categorias = Categoria::with('productos')
    ->join('compras', 'compras.idProducto', '=', 'productos.idProducto')
    ->get();  pero no se si el error es que como productos es un array que está dentro de otro array...

Answer (score 0):

Es raro que estés mezclando:

- query builder
- Relaciones de Eloquent

Entonces decantate por uno de los 2 métodos pero no ambos

Entonces si lo que tratas de obtener son todos los productos de una categoría alcanza con hacerlo así:

```
$consulta = Categoria::with('productos')->get();
```

Comment: muchas gracias pero entonces como seria el join de productos con la tabla compras que es donde me está dando el error... ademas necesito todas las categorias con sus respectivos productos...

Comment: ¿? @Anonimo que la intención no era los productos de una categoría?

Comment: @Anonimo21 listo ya te traerá todas las categorías y sus productos

Comment: Necesito hacer join de todos los productos devueltos por todas las categorias ya los productos los estoy obteniendo...

Comment: Pues eso hace está consulta verás cada categoría y sus productos o quieres los productos y su categoría?

Comment: Si pero ahora quiero hacer JOIN de los productos obtenidos con la tabla de compras...

Comment: Y no consideras que esa explicación más detallada iría mejor en la pregunta? Pues eso de las compras no lo estás preguntando

Comment: Muchas gracias por la recomendación es que también soy nuevo en esta plataforma de StackOverflow y apenas la estoy aprendiendo a usarla...

Comment: Agrega tus tablas, las relaciones entre ellas y el resultado que esperas obtener